# How to add add to cart with ajax to custom phtml

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, ajax, php-7

I have to add `add to cart` button on homepage. I have custom phtml in my own module. I would like this button to work with ajax. Could someone please suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the below code at last in your phtml file and then check after cache flush.

```
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_product->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note:** Make sure you have to set the **No** option from admin which steps i have given below.

**Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart -> After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart to No**